# TinyMCE 5 images not showing to some users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, https, tinymce, tinymce-5

I am using TinyMCE 5 on my ruby on rails app that runs on `https`. I have a Wordpress website running on `http` that hosts images.

After uploading an image to Wordpress, I copy its `HTTP` URL into tinyMCE image section and these work fine and displayed properly as well.

However, some users are complaining that they can't see images. Whenever I check it works fine. What could be the problem?

Possible reasons could be too many calls at the same time, usage of `http` for Wordpress site or slow network connection of the user.

Comment: If your site uses SSL **https** and the images path url uses the protocol **http** this will break the image.

Comment: But it works most of the time and then suddenly it stops working and then next day it is working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with the host that you are using for storing images. (maybe there is a daily limit on number of requests that you can process)

**Possible solution:**

Store your images on AWS S3 or Google Drive etc and use their links in tinyMce. It will most definitely work.